# How to uninstall reaver packages

Tags: linux, kali-linux, parrotsec

I have certain package such as Reaver v1.6.6 that I don't want at all. I tried doing:

```
sudo apt-get remove reaver
sudo apt-get purge reaver
sudo dpkg -r reaver
sudo dpkg -P reaver
```

But when I write `'reaver'` in terminal it shows me version Reaver v1.6.6.

How can I remove it properly?

Comment: As Kali is a distribution intended for experts, you should be able to find out where the program `reaver` is located and which package it belongs to. (If it is part of a software package.) Please [edit] your question and provide this information.

Comment: What does the output of the commands in your question say about the package being removed?

Comment: How did you install `reaver`?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `reaver` will break some other packages. E,g: It is a dependency for `wifite`, already installed on ParrotSec, see [debian package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/wifite).